# A = B * C, how do I solve for B

Tags: matrices, problem-solving, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

$$A = B C$$

where $A$'s dimension =  $n$ x $1$, $B$ 's dimension = $n$ x $n$, C 's dimension = $A$ = $n$ x $1$

I know A and C.

How do I solve for B?

Attempt: I was thinking about multiply by the inverse of C. But C is non invertiable because its dimension nx1.

---

Context: statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/sta305files/Rudyregularization.pdf (page 26, I am looking to solve for the Smoother Matrix S).

Comment: There is generally not a unique solution: there will be multiple $B$'s satisfying this equation. Are you looking to find just one of them?  If so, how about making $B$ diagonal, with suitable diagonal entries?

Comment: I am trying to find the smoother matrix as indicated here: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/sta305files/Rudyregularization.pdf (page 26)

Comment: @avs the process you mentioned is only valid if all the entries of $C$ are non zero.

Comment: @Dbchatto67, why?  If $C$ has a zero entry, just make the corresponding diagonal entry in $B$ zero.  $B$ only has to map the specific vector $A$ to the specific vector $C$, as I understood correctly.

Comment: @wrek, the context in your comment is important: you should included it in your question.  Otherwise, people might give your question negative votes.

Comment: @avs that gives you a zero component of the vector $A.$ But $A$ may not have any zero component.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve for a **unique** $B$. For example let $A=kC$, therefore$$BC=kC$$then the answer $B$ to the above equation includes **all matrices that have an eigenvalue $k$ and a corresponding eigenvector $C$**.

Note that if $B$ is not symmetric, then its trace is not unique. For example if$$A=C=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$and$$B=\begin{bmatrix}a&1-a\\b&1-b\end{bmatrix}$$then the equation $A=BC$ is satisfied for any $a,b\in \Bbb R$, but if $B$ is symmetric, we from $A=BC$ we can write $$C^TA=C^TBC$$therefore$$tr(C^TA)=tr(C^TBC)=tr(BC^TC)=C^TC\cdot tr(B)$$hence$$tr(B)={A^TC\over C^TC}$$where I exploited [the properties of trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: I am looking for the trace of $B$

Comment: @wrek: I think you can always get the trace of $B$ to be $0$ (assuming $n\ge 2$).